# Cuando testeo este codigo, me dice que no ha hecho nada

Tags: python

Hola amigos quiero testear este codigo porque estoy realzando un challenge pero, a la hora de testear no me aparece que lo ejecuta. les dejo el codigo por aqui:

```py
class Animal:
        def __init__(self, especie, color):
            self.edad = 0
            self.especie = especie
            self.color = color
    
    def cumplirAnios(self):
        self.edad += 1
        return self.edad

    def claseAnimal(especie, color):
        return claseAnimal(especie, color)
print(claseAnimal('Gato', 'Gris'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Te has hecho un poco de lio...

```
  # declaramos la clase
class Animal:

      # el constructor
    def __init__( self, especie, color ):
        self.edad = 0
        self.especie = especie
        self.color = color
    
      # un método para aumentar la edad y obtenerla
    def cumplirAnios( self ):
        self.edad += 1
        return self.edad
      
      # un método que nos devuelva algunos datos
    def getDatos( self ):
        return [ self.especie, self.color ]

  # creamos el animal, invocando al constructor    
turro = Animal( 'Gato', 'Gris' )

  # aumentamos su edad y obtenemos el dato
edad = turro.cumplirAnios( )

  # obtenemos los otros datos
data = turro.getDatos()
  
  # imprimimos
print( f"El animal es un {data[ 0 ]}, de color {data[ 1 ]} y de {edad} años" )
```